# SvcUtil generating Reference.cs files that don't compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I have two Silverlight projects that rely on webservices to do the grunt work. If I use the "Update Service Reference" functionality in Visual Studio (2010) to update the clients, the reference.cs files that get created don't compile.

It looks like VS/svcutil is forgetting to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and related methods (RaisePropertyChanged) on the objects it creates, but at the same time it does try to call that method in the property setters.

I have no idea when this started since it was a while since I updated those service references. My colleagues on the same codebase do not have this problem.

Does this sound familiar to anyone at all?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing the service and regenerating it helped. No idea what the problem was though.